# UITextField - If Statement

Tags: ios, xcode, if-statement, uitextfield

still new to the iPhone SDK however I am loving it so far...

im just goign through a course, tutorial online and a little confused, I am trying to basically have a UITextField and a submitbutton(AKA:GO action button on the keyboard)

h file..

```
IBOutlet UITextField *InsertUITextFieldBox;  // UITextField to input keystrokes..
IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;   // UILabel to show if answer is correct or incorrect..

}

-(IBAction)dropMyKeyboard;   // Setup to Say go - and IB - DidEndonExit on my UITextField
```

my .m file

```
-(IBAction)dropMyKeyboard{
NSString *TypedinbyUser = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [InsertUITextFieldBox text]];  //saves data in uitextfield to a nsstring

NSString *CorrectAnswer = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"http://google.com"];  //answer  to used to compare in if statement with uitextfield

                          [myLabel setText:TypedinbyUser]; // show what was typed in my user

//if statement, if what user types is correct to the CorrectAnswer, then display the following if right or wrong....
if (TypedinbyUser == CorrectAnswer) {
    [myLabel setText:@"You Answered Correctly"];
}
[myLabel setText:@"You Answered Incorrectly"];

}
```

so yeh, when I run this, and typed in "http://google.com" in my textfield and press GO - my UILabel goes to "You Answered Incorrectly"  when I know its exactly what I typed, as I copied and pasted it from my code, without the quotes, and also manually typed it in, and tried adding spaces before and after....

any help would be great as to what I am doing wrong.. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are comparing pointers to strings and not the strings themselves.  The string you typed will be at a different memory location to the test string so will have a different pointer (even though the strings themselves will be identical).

Try something like

```
if([TypedinbyUser compare:CorrectAnswer]==NSOrderedSame)
{
     // do something positive here....
} else {
     // do something negative...
}
```

Comment: Originally wrote this answer with compareNoCase: which is no in the standard libraries, I had extended the NSString class to have this method and have been using it so long forgot it wasn't standard, if you want to do caseless compare try caseInsensitiveCompare: instead.

Comment: Or `[TypedinByUser isEqualToString:CorrectAnswer]`. Just a matter of taste.

Comment: isEqualToString may be marginally more efficient in this context.

Answer (score 1):

To check if two strings are the same or not, use `- (BOOL)isEqualToString:(NSString *)aString`
.

You can find detail information here: [NSString Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/isEqualToString%3a)

For your case: `if ([TypedinbyUser isEqualToString:CorrectAnswer]) {...}`

What you're comparing is if two strings' memory location are the same or not (of corse they aren't), if you're coming from language such as Java, learn how pointer works.

Another to note is, for variable name, it should start with lower case by convention.